# Dropping spinor into a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, dirac-equation

Are there any purely formal, algebraic calculations that show what happens when one drops a [spinor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) into a black hole? No hand-waving allowed!

To make the problem precise, several definitions are needed. By "spinor", it is meant the construction of vector-like objects from the [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) of the local coordinate frame of a manifold. A simple but strong development of the idea is given in chapter one of the textbook "Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis" by Jurgen Jost. Both Weyl and Dirac spinors are presented there, as well as the idea of [spin connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection) and [frame fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_field). Please note that these spinors are *not* waves, nor do they arise from the Dirac equation. Rather, they can be thought of as "point particles", much like a "tangent vector" is a "point particle": they're just algebraic expressions that can be defined at each point of a manifold. A field of tangent vectors defines the tangent manifold; an orthonormal collection of tangent vectors defines a "frame field". The Clifford algebra of orthonormal tangent vectors defines spinors; a field of spinors defines the "[spin manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_manifold)". Some spin field might be a solution to the Dirac equation, but this is not generally the case, no more than some arbitrary vector field is the solution to the classical wave equations.

The spinors here have nothing to do with QFT, and this is not a question about QM. Spinors are "classical" objects, in the same way that scalars and vectors are "classical". By contrast, QFT arises when one takes Feynmann integrals over fields. There is no QFT or QM implied or intended in this question.

Again: to be clear: spinors have nothing to do with QM or QFT, and can be well defined as purely "classical" objects. Another book that gives a detailed treatment of the purely classical Dirac equation is David Bleeker, "Gauge Theory and Variational Principles" (1981) Addison-Wesley. This book provides mathematical details for (completely classical, non-quantum) Dirac spinors in a general curved spacetime background. The Jurgen Jost book, *op. cit.* describes how spinors are constructed on arbitrary Riemannian manifolds, in any number of dimensions. There is no need for a quantum theory, or even of a concept of "time", to consistently define spinors on arbitrary manifolds with metric.

The language for "dropping spinors" is naive. Thus, lets try replacing it with fancier language. Given the Schwarzschild spacetime, one can write down a spin connection on it. In fact, it seems one should be able to write down more than one: there is presumably a non-trivial spin cohomology. What is that cohomology? My naive intuition suggests that its probably $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ with the first $\mathbb{Z}$ arising from the 2-sphere wrapped around the singularity and the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ arising from two distinct ways of gluing the spin connection together on the two coordinate atlas charts needed to cover the 2-sphere.

Does this make sense? I think I know how to write down the spin cohomology for this situation, but perhaps I am deluding myself with some incoherent mental picture of the geometry. I'll try writing it down, shortly.

If there is the above hypothesized spin cohomology group, that would imply that there is a corresponding spin holonomy. Thus, this question is formally asking "is the spin holonomy isomorphic to the Kerr spacetime?"

We now have a formal apparatus for talking about "dropping a spinor". To wit: one has a spin field, perhaps localized in space, perhaps not. It must, by definition, be a representative of one of the elements in the spin cohomology. In and of itself, it is just a field, and has no dynamics. If we now take a space-like slice of this field, and apply the Dirac equation to it, that provides a time-like dynamical evolution. In that sense, the spinor "drops" (or perhaps "rises"). However, considering the Dirac eqn only complicates the question, by turning it into a question about harmonic forms. That would be left for a different question, after a clear answer emerges for this one.

See also a related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766369/dropping-a-spinning-top-into-a-black-hole).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146469/discussion-on-question-by-linas-dropping-spinor-into-a-black-hole); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: It seems that this question can be answered by working with the so-called "river model" of the Kerr metric, as given by Hamilton & Lisle, https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060 The background metric is given as an inflowing fluid with a rotational component. They do not give the corresponding spin connection; however, it seems the spin connection should be able to couple to spinors in such a way that a spin-frame coordinate transformation should convert into a rotational component in the so-called "river".