# Dropping a spinning top into a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, spinors, kerr-metric

Is there a formal treatment for what happens when one drops a spinning top into a black hole? More precisely, if one has a spinning top, of mass $m$ and angular momentum $j$, and lets it drop into a blackhole described by the Schwarzschild spacetime, for mass $M\gg m$, one should, in some way, find that the spacetime is described by the Kerr metric (of angular momentum $j$). Are there any purely algebraic derivations of how this happens?

I am imagining that a perturbative argument can be given. So, for example, given that the Schwarschild metric $g$ (which solves the Einstein equations), one introduces a perturbation $\delta g$ such that it describes a spinning top located far from the event horizon. One could (for instance) attempt perturbative solutions of the Einstein equations as the top falls along a geodesic (i.e. in a free-falling frame). A radial geodesic will do. It reaches the event horizon in finite proper time. At this point, the metric $g+\delta g$ should resemble or approximate the Kerr metric.

Of course, this problem can be modeled using modern software to compute the dynamical evolution of the Einstein equations. However, this is compute intensive and not particularly insightful. Thus, the question is whether there is a purely algebraic demonstration or solution?

This question is almost identical to [another stack exchange question about spinors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/766249/). This question has been reworded to make it clear that none of this is about "quantum mechanics" or "quantum field theory".  The problem is "microscopic" only in the sense that the size $r$ of the spinning top is much less than the Schwarzschild radius $R$, so that one can work in the limit of $R\gg r$.

The earlier question also engendered confusion about the double covering $\mbox{Spin}(3,1)$ of the orthogonal group $\mbox{SO}(3,1)$. In the present question, the intent is that the spinning top have an angular momentum belonging to a representation with dimension $j\gg 1$. That is, only the extremely high-dimensional representations of the Lorentz group need be considered (if that actually helps to solve the problem). In other words, the top can be understood to behave "classically" and not "quantum mechanically". There is no Dirac equation, or any waves in the present formulation (other than possible gravitational waves emitted by the perturbation). However, given that the Lorentz group is semi-simple, and high-dimensional representations can be constructed from products of low-dimensional representations, then solving this problem for $j=1/2$ is also acceptable.

It is possible that this problem is solved in some textbook or arXiv paper, but my searches so far have not come up with anything.

Comment: It looks as if you are asking for an analytic solution for a time dependent and asymmetric stress-energy tensor. It seems extremely unlikely that any such solution exists. We don't even have a solution for a non-spinning mass falling into a Schwarzschild black hole.

Answer (score 2):

There are no known closed form analytical solutions for the time dependent metric of a test particle falling into a black hole, with or without spin.

Of course, there is extensive literature on obtaining such metrics using black hole perturbation theory, this typically allows the problem to be reduced to solving a number of decoupled linear partial differential equations. This a lot easier to solve then the non-linear coupled equations of full general relativity, but still does not allow for a closed form analytical solutions, and one has to solve the PDEs numerically.

There are some general things that can be said:

- Near spacelike infinity the spacetime is going to be specified the ADM mass and angular momentum, which in your example will be given by (with $G=c=1$)
  \begin{align}
  M_{ADM} = M+m - E_{bind}\\
  L_{ADM} = j + L_{orbit},
  \end{align}
  where $E_{bind}$ is the binding energy and $l_{orbit}$ is the orbital angular angular momentum both of which can be set to zero by choosing a radially infalling geodesics starting at rest at infinity.
- As the top drops towards the black hole the mass and spin multipole moments of the spacetime will change causing the generation gravitational waves carrying off some energy and angular momentum to infinity.
- This signal ends in a ringdown; a superposition of the quasinormal modes of the final black hole.
- At late times the perturbation will asymptote to a perturbation of the initial black hole within the Kerr family with
  \begin{align}
  \delta M= m - E_{GW}\\
  \delta J =j - L_{GW},
  \end{align}
  where $E_{GW}$ and  $L_{GW}$ the energy and angular momentum radiated in GWs to infinity. Although we don't have analytical solutions of $E_{GW}$ and  $L_{GW}$, we know their general scalings
  \begin{align}
  E_{GW} \propto \frac{m^2}{M},\\
  L_{GW} \propto \frac{m j}{M}.
  \end{align}
  so both should be small compared to $m$ and $j$.